# Maps.ME generate updated maps

Tags: ios, maps

I have an iPhone and iPad with Maps.ME. The software works fine, but I am no longer able to get new maps because my hardware is rather old. I tried to manually compile and run the maps generator from GitHub [mapsme omim](https://github.com/mapsme/omim/tree/master). It seems to be generating some maps files in WMW. When I put them on my devices Maps.ME lets me zoom into these maps but shows nothing. That is, there is no pop up request message to download the needed map region, yet the map shows nothing. I tried to figure out and fix this on my own but I've had no valid progress.

Maps.Me for iOS versions 8.6.4.0 (date 190113) and 9.4.7.0 (date 191019)

Can anybody share world maps or a piece of advice on how to generate them? A piece of working scripts would also be helpful. Thank you!